# Using SELECT * from multiple tables in postgres/redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-redshift

I have 3 tables with 2 common fields for all tables `(id, timestamp)`. I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1, 
     table2, 
     table3 
WHERE id = '123' 
      and timestamp = '1704'
```

What I would expect is that it returns all the rows with the id and timestamp matching from the 3 tables. How can the query be modified to achieve this?

Comment: You are doing a cross join between the three tables. You need to properly `JOIN` them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select /*your_columns*/
   from table1 
   inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id and table1.timestamp = table2.timestamp
   inner join table3 on table2.id = table3.id and table2.timestamp = table3.timestamp
 where table1.id = '123'and table1.timestamp = '1704'
```

See more here [about JOINs](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-joins/)